# Get the list of notes

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

How to obtain the list (or e.g. collection) of guids of all notes associated with current entity?

I know that it is in some way connected with service.Retreive(...), but can't make working code.

**Attach 1:**

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    Entity entity = null;

    var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

    if (entity.Contains("new_parentopportunity"))
    {
        try
        {
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            Guid projectGuid = entity.Id;
            Guid oppGuid = ((EntityReference)entity["new_parentopportunity"]).Id;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) //Instead of 100, I'll place obtained collection.Length
            {
                Entity opp = service.Retrieve("", oppGuid, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true)); //RETREIVE ENTITY NOTE HERE
                var temop = CreateNoteAttachment(opp);
                service.Create(temp);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
        }
    }
}

private Entity CreateNoteAttachment(Entity oppNote)
{
    //some code here
}
```

**Update 1:**

I also write it in queries, can you look at this, whethere everything fine there?
[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/jwrWASQq)

Comment: Do you have some code to share? What have you tried and where are you going wrong?

Comment: @Marcus, yes I've posted the code. I don't understand what should I put into service.Retreive()

Also, I've seen a way of doing that via Constructing Queries

Comment: The plugin is about copying all the notes from one entity to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to query for related notes:

Early Bound:

```
 var  notes =
                service.AnnotationSet.Where(annotation => annotation.Opportunity_Annotation.Id == entity.Id)
                    .Select(annotation => annotation.Id)
                    .ToList();
```

FetchXml:

```
  var fetchXml = string.Format("<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
                                    "<entity name='annotation'>" +
                                    "<attribute name='annotationid' />" +
                                    "<filter type='and'>"+
                                    "<condition attribute='objectid' operator='eq' value='{0}'/>"+
                                    "</filter>"+
                                    "</entity>" +
                                    "</fetch>", entity.Id);

            var response = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
            var notes = response.Entities;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! 

But what way is less resource intensive? (I suppose xml's one, but I can't prove this)