# MS Dynamics CRM - how to test for presence of Notes records within Accounts

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to check (OnLoad) whether an Account has Notes added to it. I've tried doing this using workflows but that only tests after a Note is added rather than if they are already there i.e. On Change, On updating, On status change etc.

Also tried accessing Notes via JavaScript but seems to not be able to reach the attribute. Will paste JScript here if this will help, though that might be the wrong way to go anyway.

```
function NotesAlert() {

 // the 'notestext' field is the Notes description area

  var NotesDesc = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("notestext").getValue();

  if(NotesDesc !=null) {
     Xrm.Page.getAttribute("dt_legacyuserurn").setValue("Notes exist for 
     this Acc");
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added the JScript example that would just alert a field if a Note was added as OnChange event. Doesn't test for Notes that are already on the Account. Is there a way to check for pre-existing notes on an Account/ Contact etc ?

Comment: See my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613525/7920473

Comment: Many thanks for answering this question. I will put this into action as soon as I get a free minute to test.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is **client side** (JavaScript) or **server side** (C# plugins, workflows), you have to query the associated notes (annotations) for that particular account record & do the validation.

If you want to validate it in JS, use web api to get the [associated notes of account](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/240399) from `onLoad` & `onSave` Form events, even `onChange` of fields can be done like below.

```
var query = "/api/data/v8.2/annotations?$filter=_objectid_value eq" + accountId;
```

If you want to validate in Plugins/Workflows (custom), use [fetchxml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38250791/7920473) or [query expression to query the associated notes](https://www.powerobjects.com/2015/01/21/retrieve-and-create-attachments-associated-to-notes-of-an-entity-in-dynamics-crm/) of account from Create, Update messages.